# Is there any Interesting game for Ubuntu

Tags: games

Can you please tell me if there is any interesting game that I could play in Ubuntu?
If yes please recommend some.

Comment: and check the faqs. askubuntu is not really the place to ask for game recommendations: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Comment: I would really give this site a chance http://stabyourself.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are willing to pay, [humble bundle](http://www.humblebundle.com/) tend to have nice games. the current one (humble bundle V) has a really nice collection